# How to publish and use gradle plugin which was build as fatJar?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

How can I create fat jar for gradle plugin, publish it and then use it in another project ?

I have tried:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'group'
            artifactId = 'plugin'
            version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
            from components.shadow
        }
    }
}
```

But I am failing with applying it in another project.

Can someone show me the working example ?

Thank you for any help.